# <script type="module"> loading performance

Tags: javascript, html, performance, networking, module

I imagine a popular use case for `<script type="module">` will be for loading a "main module," from which all of a project's dependencies are resolved through a tree of `import` statements. However, on the web, it seems like this would create a loading bottleneck, as the browser could not know which scripts to download until it parsed their dependents for `import`. Contrast this to a situation where all of a project's scripts are referenced in separate `<script>` elements in the initially-delivered HTML file. The scripts could all download in parallel, while and after the HTML is parsed.

Will `<script type="module">` create a loading bottleneck? Can multiple `<script type="module">` elements on a page provide dependencies for each other, so the browser doesn't necessarily need to download and parse JavaScript to figure out what to download next?

I suppose this would be a use case for HTTP/2 PUSH_PROMISE? The server would need to statically analyze the JavaScript files and determine their dependencies ahead of time. But even if the browser could be told to download the modules early, I wonder if the pushed modules would still not *execute* until `import` was parsed. At least with `<script>`, I know they would execute at the first opportunity.

Comment: I imagine that HTTP2 could be used to mitigate a large portion of the issues. But I am very curious to an answer to this question.

Comment: None of the browsers currently support ES6 modules. Don't you think that it's a little too early for this question?

Comment: @Gothdo On the contrary, if this question has not been answered already, and ES6 module resolution is a de-optimization, it would be a little too late; standardization, implementation and adoption effort would be spent on a technology outclassed by what we already have (at least in high-performance production scenarios). My hope is that some thought has been invested here, and a prototype proves that `<script type="module">` matches or outperforms `<script>`.

Answer (score 12):

`<script type="module">` can probably load modules just as efficiently as `<script>` + a dynamic module loader.

Multiple `<script type="module">` can provide dependencies for each other. Source ([via IRC](http://logs.glob.uno/?c=freenode%23whatwg&s=19%20May%202016&e=19%20May%202016)):

> Me: If I have a `<script type="module" src="a.js">`, where "a.js" will `export` a module, and I also have `<script type="module" src="b.js">`, and "b.js" will `import "./a.js";`, will the same instance of the module created by the former `<script type="module" src="a.js">` be used?
>
> annevk: if they're in the same document, yes

This is because repeated imports draw from a per-Window "module map" (see [the spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#fetch-a-single-module-script)):

> If *module map* contains an entry with key *url*, asynchronously complete this algorithm with that entry's value, and abort these steps.

By creating multiple `<script type="module">` elements, we can avoid the "dependency tree bottleneck" by making the browser aware of the scripts it needs to download at the first opportunity.

"Module scripts" defer the evaluation of a module until all its dependencies are fetched; whereas "classic scripts" just execute, so a dynamic module loader could theoretically be faster. But if that dynamic module loader also blocks execution on dependencies, its task will probably take just as long to complete as it would with `import`. Also, the real threat to performance is probably networking; evaluation is likely so fast in comparison that it'd be trivial.

Comment: why would one self-answer a bounty question they posed? i can see it being used to transfer points from a 2nd account, but isn't this robbing Peter to pay Peter?

Comment: Initially burned out researching this, got impatient (hence the bounty) and was still too eager to find an answer, so I did, and got some closure by publishing my findings. I'm in this for knowledge, not points.

Comment: See also https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/12/modulepreload and https://caniuse.com/link-rel-modulepreload (some browsers only, as of 2020) and links under "Resources" at the second link (e.g. [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/links.html#link-type-modulepreload))

Comment: Anecdote:  My (in no way optimized) project built on a module architecture loads WAY slower than an earlier, non-module prototype.  I'm sure that adding links in the page header will improve things, but that seems to undermine some of the usefulness of modules (in that I don't have to duplicate information about dependencies in the page header).  *shrug* There are tradeoffs to everything, I guess.